# How to list all different properties in DBPedia

Tags: sparql, dbpedia, non-english

I have a burning question concerning DBpedia. Namely, I was wondering how I could search for all the  properties in DBpedia per page. The URI http://nl.dbpedia.org/property/einde concerns the property "einde". I would like to get all existing property/ pages.  This does not seem too hard, but I don't know anything about SPARQL, so that's why I want to ask for some help. Perhaps there is some kind of dump of it, but I honestly don't know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I second Joshua Taylor's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17077761/1281433), however if you want to limit the properties to the Dutch DBpedia, you need to change the `default-graph-uri` *query parameter* to `nl.dbpedia.org` and set the *SPARQL endpoint* to `nl.dbpedia.org/sparql`, as in the following query. You will get a result-set of just above 8000 elements.

```
SELECT (COUNT(DISTINCT ?pred) AS ?count)
WHERE {
  ?pred a rdf:Property .
}
```

[run query](http://nl.dbpedia.org/sparql/?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fnl.dbpedia.org&query=SELECT+DISTINCT+%3Fpred+WHERE+%7B%0D%0A++%3Fpred+a+rdf%3AProperty%0D%0A%7D%0D%0AORDER+BY+%3Fpred&format=text%2Fhtml&timeout=0&debug=on)

These are the Dutch translations of the properties that have been mapped from Wikipedia so far. The [full English list](http://mappings.dbpedia.org/index.php?title=Special:AllPages&namespace=202) is also available. According to [mappings.dbpedia.org](http://mappings.dbpedia.org/server/ontology/labels/missing/nl/#Properties), there are ~1700 properties with missing Dutch translations.

Comment: @kr1 Good catch on the language-specific nature of the query!  I haven't worked with the non-English Wikipedias much;  I didn't know the extent of [the localized datasets](http://wiki.dbpedia.org/Datasets?v=bli#h18-19).

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor, yes, those datasets are a great resource, even if there are lots of mappings missing in many languages. Dutch is one of the best-covered languages. However there are still thousands of translations missing. We move very slowly towards completeness ;-) (I sporadically help with Italian and German mappings). Btw, thanks for editing the answer!

Comment: why did you name it `?pred` ?

Answer (score 2):

Rather than asking for pages whose URLs begin with, e.g., `http://nl.dbpedia.org/property/`, we can express the query by asking “for which values of `?x` is there a triple `?x rdf:type rdf:Property` in DBpedia?”  This is a pretty simple SPARQL query to write.  Because I expected that there would be lots of properties in DBPedia, I first wrote a query to *count* how many there are, and afterward wrote a query to actually list them.

There are 48292 things in DBpedia declared to be of `rdf:type rdf:Property`, as reported by this SPARQL query, run against one of DBpedia's [SPARQL endpoints](http://dbpedia.org/sparql):

```
select COUNT( ?property ) where {
 ?property a rdf:Property
}
```

[SPARQL Results](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=select+COUNT%28+%3Fproperty+%29+where+%7B%0D%0A+%3Fproperty+a+rdf%3AProperty%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A&format=text%2Fhtml&timeout=30000&debug=on)

You can get the list by selecting `?property` instead of `COUNT( ?property )`:

```
select ?property where {
 ?property a rdf:Property
}
```

[SPARQL Results](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=select+%3Fproperty+where+%7B%0D%0A+%3Fproperty+a+rdf%3AProperty%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A&format=text%2Fhtml&timeout=30000&debug=on)

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I needed, as is the answer below!